# Hotkey for "Send to.."

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, automation, file-management

I have a lot of image files.

I want to look at files' previews in windows file explorer.
Then select files I want, press key combination to send this files to my specific folder. 
As if I press right mouse button on file and **Send To** item.

You're free to talk about all solution ways e.g. editing registry, AutoHotKey, python script etc.

Comment: You seem to already know how to do this... If you do, then note, we will not make the python/AHK script for you...

Comment: I know how car looks like, but I cannot drive, I know what Python is, and cannot program. I'm looking for solution now too.

Comment: Your question seems to be _auto-answered_ one. In windows file explorer just select files you want (left-click one by one holding the `Ctrl` key pressed), then right-click mouse button on any of them and **Send To**...

Comment: Or, instead of **Send To**, feel free to use **Copy To...** or **Move To...** or **Open with >** or ... (any item offered by the mouse right-click)

Comment: This *is* a distinct, valid question that is yet to get an answer! If the OP is asking (as appears the case) "how do I trigger `send:to` in explorer via hotkeys rather than context menu", I certainly don't see how that is answered, nor how anyone could possibly think it's "auto-answered" because you used suggestions (not minding the use) of certain approaches.